# What is defunctionalisation useful for?

Tags: compilers, program-transformation

[Defunctionalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defunctionalization) refers to program transformations which replace first-class functions and closures with conventional data structures (e.g. structs and enums), so that higher-order functions become regular functions.

What are the use-cases for this technique in a compiler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a great talk and accompanying post on exactly this topic by Jimmy Koppel:

- [The Best Refactoring You've Never Heard Of](https://www.pathsensitive.com/2019/07/the-best-refactoring-youve-never-heard.html)
- [Defunctionalization: Everybody Does It, Nobody Talks About It](https://blog.sigplan.org/2019/12/30/defunctionalization-everybody-does-it-nobody-talks-about-it/)

In a nutshell, you replace higher-order data (higher-order functions) with first-order data, thus you get all the usual benefits of first-order data:

- takes up less space (or can be compressed)
- easier to optimize
- can be serialized, and thus stored on a disk or sent over a network

The problem being in general case defunctionalization requires a whole-program analysis, which is extremely slow for programs of considerable size. But it can work in cases where all the functions involved are encapsulated in a single module.

As Koppel points out, one of the most useful use-cases for defunctionalization is in conjunction with [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). With both transformations together a compiler can produce (effectively) a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), which is useful for iterators/generators, async/await, coroutines and similar constructs.